# Error recording audio in iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

I'm getting the following error when recording audio in the iPhone Simulator using AVFoundation.  My code works fine on device.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

> 2012-09-15 17:51:39.592 MySpellings[538:3503] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-09-15 17:51:39.598 MySpellings[538:3503] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-09-15 17:51:39.607 MySpellings[538:3503] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: __*CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-09-15 17:51:39.612 MySpellings[538:3503] Error loading
>   /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn:
>   dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleHDAHALPlugIn.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleHDAHALPlugIn,
>   262): Symbol not found: _*_CFObjCIsCollectable   Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
>   2012-09-15 17:51:40.932 MySpellings[538:4907] aq@0xea13200:
>   ConvertInput: AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer returned 560226676,
>   packetCount 21 2012-09-15 17:51:42.254 MySpellings[538:c07]   flushing
>   pending input terminated - error '!dat'

Comment: possible duplicate of [prepareToRecord crashing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719758/preparetorecord-crashing)

Comment: Not sure on the dupe, my app isn't crashing and different error is displayed.

Comment: That's simply a simulator issue. No worries...

Comment: Anyway to fix it? I'm wanting to move my device to iOS 6 and use simulator to test iOS 5 compatibility.

Comment: The dupe is because it is already clear from previous messages here that some people have difficulty getting audio recording to work on the simulator.

Comment: Is there any way to record audio in Simulator ?

Comment: I have yet to find a way...

Answer (score 0):

In my case that error was shown because I used wrong bitrate:

I forgot that I used Kbps and `AVEncoderBitRateKey` uses bps.
So, after I multiplied bitrate to `1000`, error gone.

Answer (score -1):

I also had problems recording audio in the simulator when recording to m4a format  (AVFormatIDKey = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC). No audio was recorded an the console log contained an error for "AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer".

However, recording to .caf format (kAudioFormatAppleIMA4) does work and this might be a workaround solution for some people.

```
recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                  AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],
                  AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0],
                  AVSampleRateKey,
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleIMA4],
                  AVFormatIDKey,
                  nil];
```