# AVAudioRecorder throwing exception on prepareToRecord

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, avaudiorecorder

I'm running  [sample code](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/) on audio recording (source code downloadable at the end of the article). The code is like this

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                           nil];
NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];
```

However it throws an exception at prepareToRecord while running on the simulator:

[image]

It does record and it'll run fine if I just turn off the break point at exception. But this is annoying. What's wrong?

Comment: Audio Demo app works perfectly. I am not getting why its crashing for you.

Comment: That's weird. I downloaded afresh just to make sure I hadn't meddled anything. I guess it's just my system then.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre BTW, did you add break point to all exception?

Comment: I am not getting any exception. It simply recording audio and I am able to play recorded Audio file as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting this exception, too. Searching for solution. Important to note that you can only see these exceptions if you enable exception breakpoints. The app perform properly, but this is concerning. I'll keep investigating.

EDIT:
well, the answer is here: [AVAudioPlayer throws breakpoint in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683547/avaudioplayer-throws-breakpoint-in-debug-mode)
i figured that much myself, but still feel uncomfortable about having these exceptions. using different audio format while recording makes the exceptions to go away. however, i want to use the lossless format, which does cause these exceptions. hope this helps.