# Background Music causes crash in XCode

Tags: sprite-kit, mp3, avfoundation

I am trying to play my music within my game app and it crashes. But when I copy and paste the code within a different `xcode` project it works?

I'm using a 2d game engine called `SpriteKit` within `Xcode`. I play an mp3 file using the AVFoundation framework.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"backgroundMusic" withExtension:@"mp3"];

self.backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

self.backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = 1;
[self.backgroundMusic prepareToPlay];

[self.backgroundMusic play];
```

Comment: What's the error message say?

Comment: there isn't anything really just "(lldb) " in the log

Comment: type in bt followed by hitting the return key into the console/log and see what comes up. BTW, bt stands for backtrace.

Comment: What does it suppose to do i'm not familiar with the bt concept ?

Comment: Try it and you will see more information regarding your issue.

Answer (score 1):

[AVAudioPlayer throws breakpoint in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683547/avaudioplayer-throws-breakpoint-in-debug-mode)

I've had this problem before, this answer helped me:

"Add your exception breakpoint and edit the exception type from "All" to "Objective-C exceptions"

Some classes in AudioToolbox throw regular C++ exceptions. You can filter them off this way."

Comment: Well it's work not i have a new problem.. I create the AVAudioPlayer object and play the music within the scene, if i transition through to another scene and then go back to the original scene it creates another object and plays the same soundtrack twice. How do i overcome this ?

Comment: This is a new question, I'll answer it if you make it a seperate stackoverflow question. And remember to accept my answer!

Comment: Here is the link to the questions and i would accept the answer if i had enough reputation.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002052/avaudioplayer-not-working