# AvAudioPlayer not working?

Tags: sprite-kit, avaudioplayer, skscene

I create the AVAudioPlayer object and play the music within the scene, if i transition through to another scene and then go back to the original scene it creates another object and plays the same soundtrack twice. How do i overcome this ?

```
  NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"backgroundMusic" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    self.backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    self.backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.backgroundMusic prepareToPlay];



    if (self.backgroundMusic.playing == NO) {
        [self.backgroundMusic play];
    }
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SceneKit but I think one AVAudioPlayer can't play the same sound twice  - so this sounds like your code creates a new instance of the player. Since you don't show any code I can't really go further. But you can log the AVAudioPlayer and see if the object is the same (same memory address) or if they differ.

Comment: I have added my code to my question. I am wanting the same soundtrack to be played while i transition through different scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Well what do you want to do?
Do you want to play music only in that scene? Well then before you transition, stop the avaudioplayer.

```
   [audioplayer stop];
```

Or, maybe you want to start music in the scene, and let it just continue playing if you leave the scene or go back to the scene?

Well then you would need a seperate wrapper class for your music. Create a class, and just put a call to it to play music. You can check the .playing property to know if music is already playing or not.

Comment: [audioplayer stop]; would be more appropriate.

Comment: I want it to start in the scene and let it continue playing if i leave the scene or go back to it. It still doing the same thing and not working..