# App crashes when playing audio on iOS13.1

Tags: swift, avfoundation, ios13

I am building an app that runs sound files from within the main bundle with a url. When I tested this on iOS 13, everything is fine. But with the new update of 13.1 I am getting an error here on the line of code

> backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))

that says:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48

Here is the code that I am using in a custom class that runs background music when the app launches:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String){
let  sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "m4a")

do{
    try     
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: [AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers])
    backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))

}catch{
    print (error)
}
backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}
```

This all works fine in the simulator on iOS13, but crashes on a device running 13.1 It appears that the url is the issue, but I am not sure why. This same behavior happens on other screens where buttons are triggering audio files from the bundle.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change this:

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

To this:

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
```

Comment: Any solution for Objecitve C?

Comment: @Mc.Lover Remove all [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init], and init the player when it is actually used, with a proper url.

Comment: This fixes the crash for me, but there is no sound. Does anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: I am having the same problem with this line of code always triggering a crash: self.alertSoundEffect = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url). Making the above change has had no effect on this crashing behavior. Are there any other possible solutions to the inability to run that line of code on a device running ios 13.1.2?

Comment: I had the same problem as OP and making this change works perfectly, crash is gone and sound is OK. I am running Xcode 11.1 and iOS 13.1.2 tested on iPad Air 2 and iPhone 8

Comment: Although this is the solution, the answer is very simple, without any explanation. ```omanosoft```'s answer is better, if you care to understand the problem, and not just google for a line of code to just copy/paste.

Answer (score 7):

AVAudioPlayer doesn't have an init so it should be removed.

**Solution for swift**

If you initialise your AVAudioPlayer like:

```
var musicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

or

```
musicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

in any method **then remove it and declare like:**

```
var musicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
```

**Solution for Objective C**

If you initalise like

```
AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
```

**REMOVE the init part of [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init]**  to look like

```
AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer = [AVAudioPlayer alloc];
```

EDIT: If after this, your app pauses at that line, like you set the breakpoint there(but you didn't), but app run without problems after you click play/run, you shouldn't worry because it is some c level issue that doesn't affect the app. 
You can read more in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683547/avaudioplayer-throws-breakpoint-in-debug-mode)
So solution for that is to edit the breakpoint for All Exception, change the exception type from "All" to "Objective-C exceptions"

1. Go to the Breakpoint navigator in Xcode.
2. Control-click on the 'All Exceptions' line.
3. Select the 'Edit Breakpoint...' option.
4. Change the Exception from All to Objective-C.

[image]

Comment: Good answer and explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
    }
    catch {
        print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
    }
    return true
}
```