# Why does my app keep crashing since iOS 13?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My problem is that my app has been crashing since iOS 13. The app doesn't work on any iPhone anymore. A bit strange, however, is that the iPhone simulators on iOS 13 all work fine. Here is the output of the `lldb` console after I type `bt`:

```
    * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)
    frame #0: 0x00000001b952d268 AVFAudio`-[AVAudioPlayer(AVAudioPlayerPriv) privRemoveSessionListener] + 16
    frame #1: 0x00000001b952b9ac AVFAudio`-[AVAudioPlayer dealloc] + 32
    frame #2: 0x0000000100dae9e4 Ducko`@objc StartView.__ivar_destroyer(self=0x0000000101e2de70) at startView.swift:0
    frame #3: 0x00000001ac8c01e8 libobjc.A.dylib`object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112
    frame #4: 0x00000001ac8d2d14 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_destructInstance + 88
    frame #5: 0x00000001ac8d9db8 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_rootDealloc + 48
    frame #6: 0x00000001b0bd19b8 UIKitCore`-[UIResponder dealloc] + 152
    frame #7: 0x00000001e1a40900 UIKit`-[UIResponderAccessibility dealloc] + 60
    frame #8: 0x00000001c528e93c SpriteKit`-[SKNode dealloc] + 100
    frame #9: 0x00000001c52461dc SpriteKit`-[SKScene dealloc] + 332
    frame #10: 0x00000001c526bf54 SpriteKit`-[SKView _update:] + 568
    frame #11: 0x00000001c526761c SpriteKit`__51-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke.340 + 388
    frame #12: 0x00000001c5266a1c SpriteKit`-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:] + 520
    frame #13: 0x00000001c5269bd0 SpriteKit`__29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 200
    frame #14: 0x00000001c52ac180 SpriteKit`-[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 132
    frame #15: 0x0000000101c715f8 GPUToolsCore`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 168
    frame #16: 0x00000001b33dd514 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 632
    frame #17: 0x00000001b34a7774 QuartzCore`display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 264
    frame #18: 0x00000001acaed6d4 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 172
    frame #19: 0x00000001acb16e5c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    frame #20: 0x00000001acb16588 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 444
    frame #21: 0x00000001acb1145c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2168
    frame #22: 0x00000001acb108bc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
    frame #23: 0x00000001b697b328 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 104
    frame #24: 0x00000001b0ba56d4 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1936
  * frame #25: 0x0000000100d777c8 Ducko`main at AppDelegate.swift:14:7
    frame #26: 0x00000001ac99b460 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
(lldb) * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)
    frame #0: 0x00000001b952d268 AVFAudio`-[AVAudioPlayer(AVAudioPlayerPriv) privRemoveSessionListener] + 16
    frame #1: 0x00000001b952b9ac AVFAudio`-[AVAudioPlayer dealloc] + 32
    frame #2: 0x0000000100dae9e4 Ducko`@objc StartView.__ivar_destroyer(self=0x0000000101e2de70) at startView.swift:0
    frame #3: 0x00000001ac8c01e8 libobjc.A.dylib`object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 112
    frame #4: 0x00000001ac8d2d14 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_destructInstance + 88
    frame #5: 0x00000001ac8d9db8 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_rootDealloc + 48
    frame #6: 0x00000001b0bd19b8 UIKitCore`-[UIResponder dealloc] + 152
    frame #7: 0x00000001e1a40900 UIKit`-[UIResponderAccessibility dealloc] + 60
    frame #8: 0x00000001c528e93c SpriteKit`-[SKNode dealloc] + 100
    frame #9: 0x00000001c52461dc SpriteKit`-[SKScene dealloc] + 332
    frame #10: 0x00000001c526bf54 SpriteKit`-[SKView _update:] + 568
    frame #11: 0x00000001c526761c SpriteKit`__51-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:]_block_invoke.340 + 388
    frame #12: 0x00000001c5266a1c SpriteKit`-[SKView _vsyncRenderForTime:preRender:postRender:] + 520
    frame #13: 0x00000001c5269bd0 SpriteKit`__29-[SKView setUpRenderCallback]_block_invoke + 200
    frame #14: 0x00000001c52ac180 SpriteKit`-[SKDisplayLink _callbackForNextFrame:] + 132
    frame #15: 0x0000000101c715f8 GPUToolsCore`-[DYDisplayLinkInterposer forwardDisplayLinkCallback:] + 168
    frame #16: 0x00000001b33dd514 QuartzCore`CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 632
    frame #17: 0x00000001b34a7774 QuartzCore`display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 264
    frame #18: 0x00000001acaed6d4 CoreFoundation`__CFMachPortPerform + 172
    frame #19: 0x00000001acb16e5c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
    frame #20: 0x00000001acb16588 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 444
    frame #21: 0x00000001acb1145c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2168
    frame #22: 0x00000001acb108bc CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
    frame #23: 0x00000001b697b328 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 104
    frame #24: 0x00000001b0ba56d4 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1936         * frame #25: 0x0000000100d777c8 Ducko`main at AppDelegate.swift:14:7
    frame #26: 0x00000001ac99b460 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix the problem? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Please try to cleanup the formatting.. an [edit] to this question is definitely necessary for readability.  If you have any debugging attempts and output, please provide that as well.

Comment: try to follow https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-exc_bad_access-and-how-to-debug-it--cms-24544 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327082/exc-bad-access-signal-received

Comment: I have exact same problem!!!!!

Comment: Yes, any help would be great! I’ve got the same issues on my physical devices.

Comment: Declare your AVAudioPlayer variable without adding arguments. It was already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105462/app-crashes-when-playing-audio-on-ios13-1

Comment: thx so much @K4747Z, it works.

Comment: Any solution for Objective C?