# After updating to Xcode 11.1, the music playback function stopped working

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, exc-bad-access, xcode11

After updating to Xcode 11.1, the music playback function stopped working. Application stops with error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)

This is my function that played music and in xcode 10 it works:

```
func playBackgroundMusic(file: String) {
        do {
            backgroundMusic = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: "mp3")!)
            backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1
            backgroundMusic.play()
        } catch {
            print("Can't play music")
        }
    }
```

maybe someone faced such a problem?
I'm tried change mp3 file, but it not helped.

Comment: How do you declare your `backgroundMusic` ?

Comment: Check out this answer it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105462/app-crashes-when-playing-audio-on-ios13-1

Comment: @OOPer thanks for the question, he showed me where to look in the commentator's answer below. Was declared var backgroundMusic = AVAudioPlayer(). I fixed on var backgroundMusic : AVAudioPlayer()!